# Can't uninstall firewall driver from network adapter

Tags: windows, drivers, firewall, network-adapter

**Summary:**
I go to Network Connections, right-click my adapter and choose Properties. On the Networking tab, I select Agnitum Firewall Driver, then click the Uninstall button. This fails with the following message:

> Could not uninstall the Agnitum Firewall Driver feature. Agnitum Firewall Driver is still required by the following feature(s) and cannot be uninstalled until those features are uninstalled: Agnitum Firewall

**Background:**
I upgraded to Windows 11 22H2 from Windows 10. I had the nasty surprise to discover the advanced settings window for Outpost Firewall Pro wouldn't open. Trying to run the installer would produce a blank window with no text. The uninstall application also wouldn't work. So I started tearing out the firewall from my system by hand:

- The application folder is gone.
- I ran `clean.exe` that was in the application folder in Windows Safe Mode, patiently watched it for ~10 minutes in Task Manager, then it rebooted the system as expected.
- I believe the firewall drivers were afw.sys and afwcore.sys in C:\Windows\System32\drivers which I already deleted.
- I used DriverStoreExplorer to remove the firewall driver from the Windows driver store.
- There's no trace of either `afw.sys` or `afwcore.sys` in the registry.
- There's no trace of Agnitum in the registry.
- There's no trace of Outpost in the registry.

Comment: You should have done [this](https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/proper-uninstall-guide-agnitum-outpost-firewall-pro.344967/).

Answer (score 2):

Like many anti-malware suites and firewalls, Agnitum Outpost Firewall is made hard to remove, both to help prevent malefactors from disabling it, and to encourage users to keep up renewal. You will need to follow [specific procedures](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5380-agnitum-outpost-uninstaller.html):

1. Download [clean64.exe](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5380-agnitum-outpost-uninstaller.html), the tool to remove that firewall. **Rename** it to *clean.exe*.
2. Boot into Windows Safe mode by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *advanced startup*, and select *change advanced startup options*. Under *Advance startup*, select *Restart now*.
3. Run *clean.exe*. **N.B.** there is no GUI to indicate that this application is running... it may take some time, and then will reboot the PC.

After reboot, be sure that Windows Defender Firewall is running. You may need to [turn it on](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-microsoft-defender-firewall-on-or-off-ec0844f7-aebd-0583-67fe-601ecf5d774f).

Comment: Thank you, but the problem persists. I ran clean.exe that was originally in the installation folder. It behaved as expected (apart from not helping with the issue). The version linked above is older; I can't imagine that working any better.

Comment: Likely that is because you *manually* removed the files it needs to uninstall the software. One *could* reinstall, and then uninstall, but changing Registry permissions, removing the value "Outpost Firewall Pro" is the only alternative.

Comment: I can't reinstall because that produces a blank window with no text; whether I answer Yes or No to whatever that is, nothing else happens. I removed the last trace of "Outpost" from the registry, restarted the system and it made no difference. It would be really useful to know where Windows actually keeps the list of these adapter drivers.